# Test Automation of CMS based web application

Tags: automation, content-management-system, browser-automation, webautomation

We are using BrightSpot as CMS in one the projects. I am proposing a test automation approach (as below) and would like to know what anyone else is doing along similar lines.

Use Capybara/Selenium-Webdriver to automate the actual publishing of pages or drive the content editing interface of BrightSpot with Capybara DSL.
Once pages are published:
- Do structural tests on the publish page.
- Check the entered content is visible or not visible based on content model defined.

Example,

> ```
> <div id="asdfg" class="asdfg">
>   <h1 class="header">Entered Content</h1>
> </div>
> ```

Expect the published page to have a **h1 tag** under **div#asdfg** and the content is "Entered Content".

But prior to automation we will do a manual testing to check cross-browser rendering (compatibility) and responsiveness testing.

Answer (score 2):

There's a host of new tools that can help with web app/page test automation, like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), a headless version of WebKit in Node.js and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org), an API and test framework layer on top of PhantomJS. There's a swell webcast presentation that talks about both of these - [video here](https://ghostinspector.com/blog/webcast-phantomjs-casperjs-screenshot-comparison-and-ghost-inspector/).

The fellow that's presenting in the webcast built a SaaS based version for easily created automated UI tests called [Ghost Inspector](http://ghostinspector.com). The tests can run automatically from the cloud, or you can integrate tests to be run from your build/deploy/CI flow.

With [Ghost Inspector](http://ghostinspector.com), you can build that test in no time, either by using the CSS path or by using a Chrome plug-in that will record your session and construct a test for you (with all of the steps individually laid out) based on your interaction with the CMS web app. You can also run the tests with WebKit (Chrome) or Firefox engines.

Comment: Disclosure: I work for the parent company of Ghost Inspector.